# How can I use Ionic Hotspot plugin with cordova-android: 8.0.0?

Tags: ionic-framework, hotspot

When I try to install this plugin, I get this error:

```
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 8.0.0, failed version requirement: <6.3.0
```

When I downgrade cordova-android to the next lowest supported version (6.2.3) this breaks other plugins. Is there a way to use the Hotspot plugin with the latest vesion of cordova-android? I need this plugin to use the isConnectedToInternet() and/or isConnectedToInternetViaWifi() methods to confirm that the connected wifi hotspot has a confirmed internet connection (user has agreed to hotspot terms) - or maybe just the pingHost() method. The Network plugin doesn't seem to offer these features. If I can't use the Hotspot plugin with the latest version of cordova-android, is there another way I can test if the hotspot connection has an available internet connection?